# Entity with many to many not loading collection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.3

I have an entity Roster that has a collection of players.

```
public class Roster
{
    public Roster()
    {
        Players = new List<Player>();
    }

    public int RosterId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string RosterName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string PlayerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Roster> Rosters { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined the relationship using the fluent api

```
// many to many Roster - Players
modelBuilder.Entity<Roster>()
.HasMany(t => t.Players)
.WithMany(t=>t.Rosters)
.Map(m =>
{
    m.ToTable("RosterPlayers");
    m.MapLeftKey("RosterId");
    m.MapRightKey("PlayerId");
});
```

I can save a player to a roster like this

```
var roster = rosterRepository.GetById(rosterId);
var player = playerRepository.GetById(playerId);

roster.Players.Add(player);
rosterRepository.Update(roster);
...
```

However, when I retrieve the roster, the players collection is not loaded.  I verified the data exists with all the proper values and the following sql does yeild data.

```
SELECT * from Rosters r 
INNER JOIN RosterPlayers rp on r.RosterId = rp.RosterId
INNER JOIN Players p ON p.PlayerId = rp.PlayerId
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the `Players` property virtual so that EF can lazy load the collection.

```
public class Roster
{

    //...........

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively you can eager load the `Players` collection.

```
var rosters = db.Rosters.Include(r => r.Players).ToList();
```

Comment: DOH!... you spend so much time looking sometimes the most trivial problem is just simply overlooked.  thanks